# 17.10: Can not change display resolution - did work with 17.04

Tags: display, radeon, display-resolution

I have a [HP Compaq nc8430](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-compaq-nc8430/specs/) with a display which should run 1680x1050 (16:10) but after upgrading from 17.04 to 17.10 (Artful Aardvark) the resolution can only be set to 1400x1050 (4:3) and that gives elliptical circles.

One way to solve the could be to downgrade to 17.04 but that does not solve the problem in the long run.

I have `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` installed.

```
# grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[    47.455] (EE) open /dev/dri/card0: No such file or directory
[    47.469] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[    47.550] (EE) AIGLX: reverting to software rendering
```

Do I miss some `firmware`?

```
$ aptitude search firmware | egrep -i "ati|radeon"
(no result)
```

Graphics adapter is:

```
# lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV530/M56-P [Mobility Radeon X1600]
```

I tried `radeontop` but I guess the card is too old:

```
# radeontop 
Failed to open DRM node, no VRAM support.
Unknown Radeon card. <= R500 won't work, new cards might.
```

`xrandr`says the same:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1400 x 1050, current 1400 x 1050, maximum 1400 x 1050
default connected primary 1400x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  1400x1050     77.00*
```

Any help would be much appreciated.